# Jquery named function not working as callback

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Maybe this is a dumb question but i cannot understand why is happening

I have this jquery code:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Coloca datos JSON en sus respectivos campos
        function setData(data){
            $('#id').val(data.id);
            $('#name').val(data.name);
            $('#status').val(data.status);
            $('#rating').val(data.rating);
            $('#description_short').val(data.description_short);
            $('#description_long').val(data.description_long);
            image_url = (data.image_url) ? data.image_url + "?" + new Date().getTime() : 'https://via.placeholder.com/512';
            $("#image").attr('src', image_url);

            $('button[name=btn-delete]').prop('disabled', false);
        };


        $('button[name=btn-edit]').click(function(){
            $('#modal-form').attr('action', "{{route('categories.index')}}/" + $(this).data('id'));
            $.get("{{route('categories.index')}}/" + $(this).data('id') + "/edit")
            .done(function (data){
                setData(data);
        });
    });
```

Its working prefectly as intended, but if i do this:

```js
        $('button[name=btn-edit]').click(function(){
            $('#modal-form').attr('action', "{{route('categories.index')}}/" + $(this).data('id'));
            $.get("{{route('categories.index')}}/" + $(this).data('id') + "/edit")
            .done(setData(data));
        });
    });
```

My form doesn't get filled, i cannot figure why setData() doesn't function as a callback

Can somebody help me understand the difference?

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: `.done(setData(data));` calls `setData(data)` and the result of that is used by `done` ... so, it's different ... try `.done(setData);` - which is equivalent to `.done(function(x) { return setData(x);})` - note, the name of `x` is completely unimportant

Comment: mmm I'm starting to get it... but why is not necessary to pass the argument to the function?

Comment: because `.done` calls the supplied function with the arguments `(data, textStatus, jqXHR)` - you can see this by checking the arguments your callback `setData` receives ... `console.log(arguments.length)` in `setData` will output `3`

Comment: the thing to know is, if something requires a function as an argument (like done), ... `setData` is a function, `setData()` is the result of immediately calling that function - which, in this case, is not a function (a function can return a function, but that's a story for another tutorial :p)

Comment: Another way to think about it: `funcName(otherFunc(arg))` is equivalent to `let temp = otherFunc(arg); funcName(temp);` When you write it that way, you can see that the other function is called immediately.

Answer (score -1):

You can make it work by pass the reference of `setData` instead of calling it, like:

```
$('button[name=btn-edit]').click(function(){
    ...
    
    $.get("{{route('categories.index')}}/" + $(this).data('id') + "/edit")
       .done(setData);
});
```